# q.defer deferred.resolve is deprecated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred

I just saw that this code is deprecated and I have been trying to follow this guide: http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/ to use it the correct way, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Can someone help me out?

```
function fetchPlayers(callback) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(URL)
                .success(function (response) {
                    var data = angular.fromJson(response);
                    for (var g = 0; g < data.player.length; g++) {
                        var player = model.findPlayerByName(data.player[g].name);
                        if (player == null) {
                            var newPlayer = {
                                _id: (new Date).getTime(),
                                name: data.player[g].name,
                                position: data.player[g].position,
                            };
                            model.players.push(newPlayer);
                        }
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(model.players);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Comment: There's no mention of `resolve()` being deprecated in the docs for the latest version of angular. Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer was close but the `.then` method calls back with a response object, not data.

```
function fetchPlayers() {
    return $http.get(URL)
        .then(function onFulfilled(response) {
            //DO This
            var data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
            //NOT This
            //var data = angular.fromJson(response);
            
            for (var g = 0; g < data.player.length; g++) {
                var player = model.findPlayerByName(data.player[g].name);
                if (player == null) {
                    var newPlayer = {
                        _id: (new Date).getTime(),
                        name: data.player[g].name,
                        position: data.player[g].position,
                    };
                    model.players.push(newPlayer);
                }
            }
            return model.players;
        });
}
```

From the Docs:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - config – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

-- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Comment: Ah! perfect, i knew i must have been close, the other answer is what i had when i tried it on my own as well.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it should just be:

```
function fetchPlayers(callback) {
    return $http.get(URL)
        .then(function (response) {
            var data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
            for (var g = 0; g < data.player.length; g++) {
                var player = model.findPlayerByName(data.player[g].name);
                if (player == null) {
                    var newPlayer = {
                        _id: (new Date).getTime(),
                        name: data.player[g].name,
                        position: data.player[g].position,
                    };
                    model.players.push(newPlayer);
                }
            }
            return model.players;
        });
}
```

Basically,

- change all `promise.success(callback)` to `promise.then(callback)`
- return the promise directly rather than creating an extra deferred object that gets resolved when the first promise resolves.
- (Note) The return value of the `callback` gets forwarded to the next promise in the chain.

Comment: so this is actually what i just had and i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` on the `data.goalie.length` (which i edited to player above i realized i hadn't fixed that when appending my code)

Comment: Upvoted because it is so close, but couldnt give you the answer.  See the answer @georgeawg provided